# Textbox Mode DateTimeLocal not working when deployed to IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, iis, textbox

> Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource
>   required to service this request. Please review the following specific
>   parse error details and modify your source file appropriately.
>
> Parser Error Message: Cannot create an object of type
>   'System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBoxMode' from its string representation
>   'DateTimeLocal' for the 'TextMode' property.
>
> Source Error:

I set my `Textbox` `TextMode=DateTimeLocal` and ran my project and it runs well. When I tried to deploy my application to IIS and visit the webpage i would get the error above. `IIS` has `.Net 4.0.30319`. Is there a reason why i get it on `localhost` (on my computer) and not the server (iss)? how do i fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are only three members in the [TextBoxMode Enumeration for ASP.NET 4.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.textboxmode%28v=vs.100%29.aspx):

1. SingleLine: Represents single-line entry mode.
2. MultiLine: Represents multiline entry mode.
3. Password: Represents password entry mode.

There are a considerable amount more, including `DateTimeLocal` in  [TextBoxMode Enumeration for ASP.NET 4.5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.textboxmode.aspx).

Your localhost is running ASP.NET 4.5, and apparently your server is not... ensure you have ASP.NET 4.5 installed on your server.

**UPDATE:** for people who can't upgrade to ASP.NET 4.5, you can likely just set the `type="datetime-local"` for the TextBox as an alternative.

Comment: Correct. I had to install asp.net 4.5 and it works. Only funny thing is it does work on IE 9 .. dont know if it will work on the later version. works fine on chrome though.

Comment: @DineshPersaud I don't think IE9 supports HTML5 input types (at least not all of them). I also added an alternative that should work in ASP.NET 4.

Answer (score 1):

Install asp.net 4.5 on server and works!