# Parse Error when application is deployed to IIS

Tags: asp.net, .net, iis-7, .net-4.0

I have an ASP.NET application written in .NET 4.0. When I run the application through Visual Studio, everything works and looks good. Same thing when I deploy it to IIS7 on my local machine. However, when I deploy it to **another box** running on Windows Server 2008 R2 with .NET 4.0 and IIS7, I get the following parse error:

```
 Cannot create an object of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBoxMode' from its 
 string representation 'Number' for the 'TextMode' property.
```

It's complaining that the `TextMode` property on `asp:TextBox` doesn't contain the `Number` option, even though it works perfectly fine on my local IIS. I [came across this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19185524/textbox-mode-datetimelocal-not-working-when-deployed-to-iis) and people are suggesting the two machines have different .NET versions. This is not the case for me; both machines are have .NET 4.0 and IIS7.

Besides this error, other pages are also rendered differently style-wise. For example, IIS on the server machine doesn't respect the `Width` property on any of the `asp:TextBox` controls; I have to apply the width as a style, even though my local IIS renders them just fine. I'm using IE10 w/o compatibility mode.

I originally thought the problem might have been with missing `js` or `style` files, but IE reports success status for all content files  in the `Network Profiler` window.

I'm truly lost at this point. The code, IIS settings, and .NET versions are exactly identical on these two boxes, but the pages are rendered differently. The only thing I can think of is that some other Web component was installed with Visual Studio that is changing the way IIS renders aspx pages. Is that possible? If anyone has come across this issue at some point I'd appreciate it if you could give me some pointers as to what could be causing the issue.

Comment: Is the application pool running .Net version 4.0 on the server?

Answer (score 0):

So I finally figured out what the problem was. The parse error did in fact have something to do with .NET. I have .NET 4.5 installed on my machine but not on the server. What I'm still confused about is that the target version for my application is 4.5, so if the `Number` option exists only in 4.5, why does Visual Studio even display it? Not sure if that's a bug or if I'm overlooking something.

As for the discrepancies between local and server IIS, it turned out I had to install the [ASP.NET Browser Definitions Hotfix (KB2600088)](https://support2.microsoft.com/kb/2600088?wa=wsignin1.0) on the server. That fixed all the styling issues.